# Display Only Matched Rows Within a Container and Rotate into and Out Of View

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatable

**Updated:  I added a JSFiddle of what I am working with.
Basically any way to contain the data within the given containers.
http://jsfiddle.net/donlaur/K8q5P/1/**

**Forked Version is closer, moving up and down.  http://jsfiddle.net/donlaur/u87VQ/5/**

I have a HTML5 page with jQuery that I am working on.  I have most of my components working as they should.  I am just missing one element.  I will describe what I need and hopefully you can help get me there.  I am leaving out parts of this because it might not be reverent to the snippet and part that I need.

Let's say I have a table of 6 rows.  Half are from A-F and the other from G-Z.  I have a link that when clicked shows the 3 rows that are from A-F and the other link shows the other 3 from G-Z.  If I click show all it shows all 5 rows.  I default by having the class matched to all rows.  When I filter by alphabet I remove the matched for all and then only add it back to my matched set.  So, when I click on A-F only the ones with filtercriteria from A-F will have a class of matched.

I have these in a container and I only want to show 2 rows at a time.  I also have a link to go up and a link to go down and traverse these rows.  The other rows outside of the 2 are in the container but set to overflow:hidden.

If I click my A-F link and those elements match that A-F I add a class called matched to those rows.  I have one visible row that is highlighted, and I call that highlighted focused row on and I add a class of 'on' to the row.  The up and down will move this on class through my remaining results.

The problem is that if I have 5 elements that I have matched or 10 if I click on show all, I am only displaying 3 in my container.  I need to move the rows in and out of view.  I already have the other non-matched rows set to display:none.

My Table.

```
<table id="data-container">
<thead><th>Name</th><th>Nickname</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr id="C1" class="matched on" filtercriteria="C"><td>Cameron</td><td>Cam</td></tr>
<tr id="D1" class="matched" filtercriteria="D"><td>Donnie</td><td>Don</td></tr>
<tr id="E1" class="matched" filtercriteria="E"><td>Edward</td><td>Ed</td></tr>
<tr id="J2" class="matched" filtercriteria="J"><td>James</td><td>Jimmy</td></tr>
<tr id="J3" class="matched" filtercriteria="J"><td>Johnny</td><td>John</td></tr>
<tr id="T22" class="matched" filtercriteria="T"><td>Timothy</td><td>Timmy</td></tr>
</table>
<a class="UP" href="javascript:void(0);">up</a>
<a class="DOWN" href="javascript:void(0);">down</a>
<a href="PICK" href="javascript:void(0);">pick</a>
```

What I need.
3 elements or more showing in a container that only fits 2 elements with an up and down link that moves the on class up and down.  Item items that are matched but outside of the view of the container would rotate back into the view.  When the pick link is clicked the id of the tr that is set to on or the current highlighted row will display that data on a div below.  If the selected highlight of on is currently on tr of #T22 then Timmy will show in a div below.

You can not click on the Timothy row, you have to select it using up and down and the pick link.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote?  At any rate, any way to do this that would work would be ok, including using a carousel for my data and rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to determine on the UP/DOWN click if the current row is the first/last child on the table and execute the row shift only if not.

```
$("a.DOWN").click(function () {
    var currRow = $(".on");
    var lastRow = $('#data-container tr:last-child');

    if (currRow.attr("id") != lastRow.attr("id")) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Full demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3LLvx/